# Accessing blender from another computer

Tags: workflow

Good day! This may be completely the wrong forum for this question, and if it is I apologize, but I figure since it's kinda related to Blender, I'll ask here first.

So I have a desktop running Linux and is the main computer I use Blender with. I also have a Linux laptop that I would like to use to remote into the desktop to run blender. Now I am not talking about remoting in to use a command line. I want to be able to USE blender like I am sitting in front of my desktop.

I've heard of solutions such as TeamViewer, but had problems with that solution as TeamViewer filled up my HDD with log files and I also found it to be quirky even on my home network.

I've also heard of ssh with x-forwarding, but don't know much about that or if it would do the trick.

Basically, like I said I want to be able to sit on my couch and use blender, OR be able to sit in a coffee shop and use blender.

If anyone has any answers, or a better idea on where to post this question, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for a recommendation for remote desktop software.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't load Blender on the laptop; that's what I do.. But I'm, with Ray, that this question is out of scope of the site.

Comment: If you do load Blender into the laptop and it's a bit slow as my old laptop is, try not using texturing or Material mode until you absolutely have to.  Slow computers can work satisfactorily in solid mode.

Comment: It is quite possible to do what you want to do. Any VNC viewer on one computer and a VNC server or similar on the other will work just fine. Since you are using Linux you don't have to deal with the limitations of RDP on windows. Note that the client computer does not have to be even the same OS...The speed of the connection however will be the determining factor on how much or how little you enjoy the experience...

Comment: Thank you. I shall look into that. I appreciate the responses, even though this question was off-topic. I now have a better direction. Thanks.